# Nature of the Stack Exchange data dumps

Tags: support

I was exploring the latest Stack exchange data dump (published on May 2, 2014). Are these dumps cumulative ? I understand that similar dumps have been released since 2009. So does this dump include cumulative data since 2009 ? Or is each dump completely independent and does not include any data from previous dumps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, dumps are cumulative and include the data from all previous dumps, provided the posts have not been deleted. (Deleted posts are not included, but may of course remain in the dumps before they were deleted.)